# How to read values from multiple input fields in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, append

Thanks for looking into this in advance. It's basically my first week of javascript, so apologies if it is something common and I appreciate a link to a similar question.

I can't figure out how to extract values from my dropdown and text input at the same time so I can then append that information to another container. Here is my html:

```
<div class=“container1”>
   <select class=“options_selector”>
     <option val=“admin”>admin</option>
     <option val=“user”>user</option>
   </select>
   <input class=“user_name” type="text"/>
</div>

<div class=“container2”>
   <!— append stuff here —>
</div>
```

So information from container1 should get appended to container2. For example, if I chose 'admin' in options_selector and typed 'freddy' in user_name input box, container2 should now have 'admin freddy' in it. When, then, I change the select box value to 'user' and the input text to 'john' - container2 should have another piece of text appended 'user john'.

I know it can be done with on change events, but i cannot figure out the general idea behind extracting both of those pieces of information together.

I'm using jquery as a framework by the way.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need to extract the two values at once. You can extract them separately and then concatenate them.

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? If so, post your code.

Comment: @Regent yes, but I honestly honestly am not a programmer, and have no idea how to actually do it.

Comment: @PM77-1 could you elaborate please? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write code like :

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
str += $( this ).text() + " ";
});
$( "#user_name" ).val(str);
}).change();
```

[JSFiddle Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/duhv4sus/)

Comment: partially got what I was thinking. Thank you Vivek:) What I mainly meant is that input field will be edited too by a user and $('select').val() wouldn't change the input, but only the container2. However, it's a good kickstart for me, i'll try to work on the rest of it. appreciate it!:)

Comment: I Did what i understand ! pardon me !

Comment: @Regent it's cool, I'll get the rest of it working:) I guess I needed to understand the general direction of solution!:)

Comment: @MelFunks well, nevertheless I have done the rest: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/duhv4sus/1/)